# Accountable to / for: which one is better in the following context and why?

Tags: prepositions

Accountable to / for -- which one is better in the following context and why?

A doctor is accountable to take complete care of his/her patients and guide them both mentally and physically towards a healthy life and a balanced diet.

A doctor is accountable for taking complete care of his/her
patients and guiding them both mentally and physically towards a healthy life and a balanced diet.

Answer (score 1):

You are accountable **to someone**, but accountable **for something**.  As "taking complete care" is an action rather than a person, the second alternative is correct.  It would, however, read more naturally, "A doctor is accountable for **the complete care** of his/her patients."